# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the crossover genetic operator?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, mutation, genetic, crossover

For example, we have this problem:

**Maximise the function f(X) = X^2 , with 0 ≤ X ≤ 31**

Using binary encoding we can represent individuals using 5 bits. After undergoing a selection method, we get to the genetic operators.

For this problem (or any optimisation problem), what are the advantages and disadvantages of the following:

- High or Low crossover rate
- Using 1-Point crossover
- Using multi-point crossover
- Using Uniform crossover

Here's what I came up with so far:

- High crossover rates and multi-point crossover can decrease the quality of parents with good fitness, and produce worse offspring
- Low crossover rates mean the solution will take longer to converge to some optima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer as more information is needed what exactly the 5 bits represent, but I gave it a try:

- A high crossover rate causes the genomes in the next generation to be more random, as there will be more genomes that are a mix of previous generation genomes
- A low crossover rate keeps fit genomes from the previous generation, although it decreases the chance that a very fit genome will be produced by crossover operation
- Uniform crossover will create genomes that will be very different from their parents if their parents are not similar. If its parents *are* similar, the offspring will be similar to its parents.
- Using 1-point crossover means that offspring genomes will be less diverse, they will be quite similar to their parents.
- Using multi-point crossover is basically a mix between 1-point and uniform, depending on the amount of points.

Comment: Apologies, the 5 bits represent the binary representation of decimal X. Thank you for the explanation!